# I have 4 identical sprites that don't do the same thing, Why?

Tags: mit-scratch

I have four identical scratch sprites, but only one of them do what I expect and I need to know why so I can continue with  my project

I have tried reloading the page multiple times but it still won't work

When (Green Flag) clicked
forever:
        if touching mouse-pointer? then:
                                        set (Enclosure Hover) to 1
        else:
             set (Enclosure hover) to 0

I expect this to change Enclosure Hover to 1 when the mouse is touching it but it doesn't change it at all.

Comment: Do you have any scripts that are using one of those sprites in another sprite? Can you share the project and link to it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the variable is global, all sprites will compete to change it. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

If 1 sprite tries to set [Enclosure Hover] to 1, it will only happen for a split second because the other sprites that are not touching the mouse pointer, are setting it to 0.

**FIX**: Make multiple variables (with different names) for each sprite and check if any of the variables are 1, then set [Enclosed Hover] to 1 else set it to 0

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the code to all the sprites that you want. Duplicating a sprite, then adding code to one of the sprites does not add the code to every sprite.

Comment: I know that and have come up with an alternative for what I wanted to do

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add code to one sprite, then duplicate the sprite with the code in it. The code will be duplicated along with the new sprite.

Comment: Funnily enough, you described exactly what I did! I have come up with an alternative to this problem, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to duplicate the sprite only after the sprite has the code in it so that the 4 sprites do the same thing. I guess what you have been doing is to duplicate the sprites then adding the script into only one of them.